# Loop through both category group and tag group in single loop

Tags: loop

Is is possible to loop through both a category group and tag group in a for loop?

Categories: blue, red, orange
Tags: basketball

Loop displays: basketball, blue, orange, red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you (untested).

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('myCategoryGroup').find %}
{% set tags = craft.tags.group('myTagGroup').find %}
{% set elements = categories|merge(tags) %}
<ul>
    {% for element in elements %}
        <li>{{ element.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sorting them alphabetically is a little more difficult. For that you may want to try twig's [sort filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/sort.html) or, failing that, the [supersort](http://michaelrog.com/craft/supersort) or [craft-twig-better-sort](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort) plugins.